# How can I stop a google-apps-script from running on a suspended Google Apps account?

Tags: google-apps-script

Years ago I setup a Google Apps Script to allow me to "snooze" emails in Gmail. I have recently closed that Google Apps account. I am now simply forwarding all emails for that domain to another account that I have. I forgot to stop the Google Apps Script before closing my Google Apps account. I am now getting App Script Notification emails telling me that my Google Apps Script has recently failed to finish successfully. But, I do not see a way to stop this script from running.

Answer (score 0):

To stop [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization#revoking_access_rights) from accessing your data, you need to revoke it's access.

Here are the steps on how to do that:

1. Visit the [permissions](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions) page for your Google account. (To navigate to this page in the future, visit Google.com, then click your account picture in the top-right corner of the screen. Next, click **Account**, then **Security**, then **View all** in the account permissions section.)
2. Click the name of the script whose authorization you want to revoke, then click **Revoke access** on the right.

Check also this [page](http://ctrlq.org/help/424-permanently-stop-google-scripts) for more information.